# Create Excel Pivot Charts Or Graphs From Multiple Pivot Table Data Set

Tags: excel, graph, dataset, microstrategy

I have a data set with multiple dimensions, time range and metrics but not in a standard format to create pivot charts. My objective is to create graphs which will show the time series data of the metrics by the offer types.

I can edit and create appropriate columns and make the completely tabular but that will require some work. Is there any other way? I also have access to [microstrategy](https://www.microstrategy.com).

[image: spreadsheet of pivot tables]

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to pivot charts in Excel, one usually has to abide by the command: "Thou shalt flatten!" Pivot charts are created from memory objects call pivot caches, which contain n-dimensional cube data derived from structured data sources, such as Excel tables. The following [Contextures article](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot01.html) has a good example.

If you plan on creating pivot charts from your data, it will have to be properly structured. You will also have to transform your data from a wide to a long format, so that each data point has it's own row, with categories and values appearing in their own columns. Your input data should look something like this:

---

```
Offer Type          Metric            Quarter  Period    Value
Activation Offers   Number of offers  Q2 2016  Period 6  6
Activation Offers   Total Circulation Q2 2016  Period 6  2,020,000
...                 ...               ...      ...       ...
```

---

I am not familiar with microstrategy; however, given the layout of the data in your example, rearranging your data should be relatively straightforward. If your outputs are in the form of pivot tables, you may need to convert them to normal ranges (see the paste special options). Note that my example structure assumes that quarterly data can be computed from the data in each period. You may have to play around with the pivot table metrics it so that it produces the figures you are looking for.

If you decide that base Excel isn't able to produce what you need, I suggest looking into [Excel PowerPivot](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-Pivot-Powerful-data-analysis-and-data-modeling-in-Excel-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045), which would allow you to construct more complex pivot tables. PowerPivot is available as a free add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013, and is included in the Pro and Enterprise versions of Excel 2016.